# Table not showing correct value on search

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code does not show the correct value

```
function showOffice(str) {
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("selectOffice").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","officeData.php?office_id="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

this is my function for show office.

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr >
                <td><input style="width: 50%;"type="text" id="searchOffice" class="form-control" onkeypress="showOffice(this.value)"  placeholder="Search Office..."></td>
            </tr>
            </table>

    <div id="selectOffice"></div>
```

and I will be using the jquery for this. selectOffice table is in a different file.

*If my code or question is insufficient, please message me and I will send the files. Thank you so much*

Comment: what value do you want it to show and what value does it currently show?

Comment: If you're using jQuery then there are MUCH simpler ways to make an ajax request.  Also you might like to consider using `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)` to see what data is being returned, to make sure it is what you're expecting

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set respond text to value of the text box.

document.getElementById("selectOffice").value = xmlhttp.responseText;